# Problems counting zeroes standing at the beginning of rows in a matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix, count, zero

In Python I have tried to use the code below to fill a list with occurences of zeroes in rows of a matrix. These 0 must stand before all the non zero-numbers: for example in a row like [0,0,3,0] I would count only the first two zeroes.

```
occurence_of_zeroes=[0]*dim
for i in range(dim):
   for j in range(dim):
      while matrix[i][j]==0:
         occurence_of_zeroes[i]=occurence_of_zeroes[i]+1
   print("In row ",i+1," there are ",occurence_of_zeroes[i]," zeroes at the beginning")
print("Is this working?")
```

when I try to execute the code with previously defined `dim` and `matrix`, the console never spits out the result and freezes. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't exit the while loop to increment `j`. Here's a fix to your code.

```
occurence_of_zeroes=[0]*dim
for i in range(dim):
    for j in range(dim):
        if matrix[i][j]!=0:
            break    
        occurence_of_zeroes[i]=occurence_of_zeroes[i]+1
    print("In row ",i+1," there are ",occurence_of_zeroes[i]," zeroes at the beginning")
print("Is this working?")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reaching an infinite loop in that `while` because inside it you don't update any variable for it's condition

I assume what you want is something like below.

```
matrix = [
    [0, 2, 3],
    [0, 0, 3],
    [0, 1, 0],
]
dim = 3 # 3 rows 3 columns I suppose
occurence_of_zeroes=[[] for _ in range(dim)]
for i in range(dim):
    j = 0
    while matrix[i][j]==0:
        occurence_of_zeroes[i].append(j)
        j+=1

print(occurence_of_zeroes)
"""
[
    [0], 
    [0, 1], 
    [0]
]
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while matrix[i][j]==0:
     occurence_of_zeroes[i]=occurence_of_zeroes[i]+1
```

is an infinite loop. Simply use if statement instead.

```
occurence_of_zeroes=[0]*dim
for i in range(dim):
   for j in range(dim):
      if matrix[i][j]==0:
         occurence_of_zeroes[i]=occurence_of_zeroes[i]+1
   print("In row ",i+1," there are ",occurence_of_zeroes[i]," zeroes at the beginning")
print("Is this working?")
```

Comment: This would count also the zeroes coming after non-zero elements, however thanks for pointing out the problem with the while loop!